# vue-cli Vue init webpack template gives unexpected token error

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I get the message

```
 vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/webpack: Unexpected token ...
```

When i attempt to create a new project

Im using 
Node version 6.12..3

Npm version 3.10.10

Vue cli version 2.9.2

Answer (score 3):

Update your `node` by installing the latest version 9.4.0 [from their official site](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Then update `npm` by running `npm install npm@latest -g`

Then run these commands again:

```
npm install vue

npm install --global vue-cli

vue init webpack my-project-name
```

Don't forget to change `my-project-name` to the name of your project.

I've just did that and it successfully created a new Vue project with Webpack